# Can you run more than one app at a time on node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

Can you run more than one app at a time on node.js? 
...to elaborate, I mean have more than one app with access keys (3 different sets) included, running similar api calls but slightly different. I need to do three at the same time. Is this possible?

Please help. Thank you for your time and consideration. :)
much love <3

Comment: what do you mean by access keys? please can you include an example of what you're trying to do

Comment: Why can't you just whichever set of access keys you need for a given operation?  Put each in different files and load those files as needed.  Or code them each into different variables and use as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to run seperate apps. If you have these access keys in configuration like so, you can think more along these terms:

For this example, you'll need to install async (`npm install --save async`)

```
var facebookKey = 'my-access-key-for-fb',
    twitterKey = 'my-access-key-for-twitter',
    pinterestKey = 'my-access-key-for-pinterest';

async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
        facebook.request(facebookKey, '/me', function(err, facebookResults) {
            done(err, facebookResults);
        })
    },
    function(fbResults, done) {
        twitter.request(twitterKey, '/me', function(err, twitterResults) {
            done(err, fbResults, twitterResults);
        })
    },
    function(twitterResults, fbResults, done) {
        pinterest.request(pinterestKey, '/me', function(err, pinterestResults) {
            done(err, fbResults, twitterResults, pinterestResults);
        })
    }
], function(err, fb, twitter, pinterest) {
    if(err) {
        throw new Error(err.toString());
    }
    else {
        // All of your results are in here :)
        console.log(fb, twitter, pinterest);
    }
});
```

Comment: O.k... I see how that makes sense, but what about all run synchronous instead of asynchronous?

Comment: You're unlikely to be able to get these requests to run synchronously - by it's design, Node favours callbacks in order to not block the main application process. I'm sure you can achieve what you're after asynchronously.